# ESD label requirements

Tags: pcb, markings

We buy a board which has been designed in Germany specifically for us, the board is manufactured in China and delivered straight to our manufacturing plant (not in Germany).

There is a ESD label on the board that likes to come off and potentially get stuck in not so suitable places inside our products (we remove them by hand before mounting the boards instead).

[image: ESD label]

Are there any regulations in Germany that requires that such labels be mounted on all PCBs?

Comment: *Are there any regulations* Not that I know. It would not make sense either, it is just a warning sticker. It is your (company's) board, if you would like to treat it non-ESD safe that is your choice. That sticker has no meaning other than a warning. A more sensible supplier would just include the logo in the PCB's markings, maybe this PCB does not have that so they used a sticker (of poor quality so it gets loose).

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question as I am not in Germany, but I always put ESD warnings/markings in the PCB silkscreen. A sticker is sort of a half-***ed way of doing it

Comment: We have been trying to get the drawings updated for a very long time, but all attempts are just met with silence, that is why I started wondering if they think it is such a stupid question that it doesn't even deserve an answer... ;)

Comment: Demand certification on what the sticker is made of ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they should stencil on an ESD warning, saving time by not adding ESD labels later in assembly. But, I see that they don't label any of the components in the picture, making it hard to rework or repair that board later on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no regulations regarding labeling the PCB with such a label.

Only on the enclosure near the eg. RF connectors, if they are to be exempt from ESD testing in regards to a CE approval.

As specified in the RED, clause 9.3:
[ETSI EN 301 489-1](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/301400_301499/30148901/01.09.02_60/en_30148901v010902p.pdf)